# String compare not returning True for same strings in Java

Tags: string, comparison

I am comparing two strings to enter an if condition. Despite the strings being same it still enters else. This is Java 8 if that makes a difference. Not sure what could be going wrong here. Here is my code-

public String broadcast(String[] bcc, String from, String subject,
         String message, Boolean html) throws Exception {

```
  logger.info("Entering broadcast(). before if, value of bcc[0]" + bcc[0]);

  if (bcc[0]=="sendtoall") {
     logger.info("Entering UtilDelegate.java: broadcast(). Inside if" + bcc[0]);

  }
  else {
     logger.info("Entering UtilDelegate.java: broadcast(). Inside else ");

  }
```

Server log-
     Entering broadcast(). before if, value of bcc[0]sendtoall
     Entering UtilDelegate.java: broadcast(). Inside else

I appreciate your help.

Comment: I didn't have any experience with Java but think it will be answer for your question   https://www.baeldung.com/java-compare-strings  And could you change == to equals()  ?

Comment: It worked. Not sure why it was not working in my code but was working on a trial code in online compiler. Thanks for your help